# Solr Facet Index Sorting not working for numerics

Tags: solr, faceted-search

I'm using Solr for offering faceted autosuggestion.I'm using latest version of Solr.

Here is an example what I need to do.

The suggestion order should be

grade 1
grade 2
grade 3
grade 4
...
...
grade 10

But now it look like this...
grade 1
grade 10
grade 11
grade 12
grade 2
grade 3
...
...

I am using facet.sort=index .
Any idea how to do this??Please advise..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index as 001, 002, 003, ... 999 and remove the leading zeroes in your front end.

Comment: Any other way??Or is it a proper way??

Comment: Or have a separate "grade_num" int-field that you facet over and add "Grade" in your front end. Any lexical sort order will make 10 come before 2, so for strings this will be the sort order unless you make a change like Toke suggests.

Comment: I forgot that facet.sort worked properly on numerics, MatsLindh (I just checked and it does). Yours is the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Word 'grade' is useless to index. If you index the actual numeric grade, e.g., 1,2,3,...,10, then you can sort it. And if you make its type double, by default it is sorted numerically. Like the example below:

`/select?q=*%3A*&fq=ZIP_code%3D94602&fq=Year%3A[1999+TO+2013]&fq=NOT+Causes_of_Death:OTH&fl=Year,Causes_of_Death,Count&wt=csv&indent=true&rows=200&sort=Count+desc`

`Year,Causes_of_Death,Count
2000,HTD,68
2002,HTD,64
1999,CAN,61
1999,HTD,60
2005,CAN,60
2001,CAN,57`

Hope this helps.